# Using matplotlib in SublimeREPL : python interpreter stop fonctionning after "plt.show()"

Tags: matplotlib, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

I'm using sublime text 3 with REPL in python. My version of Python is python 3.5@64bits. It's not the Anaconda distribution, but a standalone version. I have been using pandas and numpy for a while without any troubles.

I am having trouble plotting with Matplotlib : my interpreter stop running after having call the show() method on a figure. 
Using this code snippet, from the matplotlib documentation :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

[I get the following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zeabz.png). The second print("test") is never evaluated, and i have to restart REPL even if i close the plot's window.

My REPL settings are the following :

```
    {
    "cmd": ["C:\\Documents \\Sublime \\python-3.5.3.amd64\\python.exe", "-i", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",
    "shell": true
}
```

I have so far tried to :

- Switch matplotlib backends
- According to matplotib documentation : I have switched to the interactive mode with ion() method / with the matplot.interactive(True)
- Reinstall matplotlib
- Use matplotilb wit bloc=False param

Does anyone know how to get the interpreter working after having plot ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `plt.show(block=False)`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. I also tried with block-False but it doesn't work